# How to calculate difference between two moments in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, momentjs

I'm trying to calculate the duration (difference between two moments) for example currently I'm working on a react native project in which I have to calculate the time spent on a screen/card.
So right now I'm trying to calculate time spent like this:

```
import moment from 'moment';
// lets say i have 3 states to note time
const [startTime, setStartTime] = useState(moment());
const [endTime, setEndTime] = useState(moment());
const [elapsedTime, setElapsedTime] = useState(Number);

// assume i have a bottomSheet, so whenever that bottom sheet goes up the timer starts and when it goes down to original position, timer stops and calculate difference/duration in minutes.
// so for the onOpenStart on onCloseEnd props of the bottomsheet, this is my function:


const start = () => {
  setStartTime(moment());
}

const end = () => {
  setEndTime(moment());
  const et = moment.duration(endTime.diff(startTime)).asSeconds();
  setElapsedTime(et);
  console.log(elapsedTime) // if i try for 10 seconds it logs 34, or sometimes -6, it's just not right
}
```

I tried to do with `new Date` method and if i try for 10 seconds it logs 34, or sometimes -6, it's just not right but could not succeed...
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your particular case, I don't think you even need `moment` library. It's super heavy in the bundle and it's just not needed.

1. You don't need to initialise the state with the dates. You don't care about them when the component just mounts, do you? You want to keep track of the dates when your functions `start` and `end` get triggered.
2. The current behaviour is that way because `useState` is async. That means that you're trying to to set the state and then use this value in the next line for some calculation - that just won't work.
3. What you can do is to use `useRef` instead of `useState`. This way you will make sure that the value that you have is the freshest one across your component.

   ```
    const startTime = useRef(new Date());
    const endTime = useRef(new Date());
    const [elapsedTime, setElapsedTime] = useState();

    const start = () => {
      startTime.current = new Date();
    }

    const end = () => {
      endTime.current = new Date();
      const et = (startTime.current - endTime.current) / 1000 // get the seconds
      setElapsedTime(et);
      console.log(et); // You cannot log elapsedTime here, because again, useState is async
     }
   ```
4. I don't know what you need to do with the elapsed time, you might not need the state either. For now I've left it as state.
5. Last thing: I really recommend looking at [day.js](https://day.js.org/) library, as it does the same things (in 99% of cases) as moment, but is much much lighter.

Comment: hey I tried, but there are some errors like in start function,`Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'null'` ...

Comment: Are you using typescript? I've never worked with it, but remove the `null` from the initalisation of useRef, that should do it. Or else initialise it with a `new Date()`.

Comment: yess, then i think it doesnt matter right, or does it

Comment: I've added the dates inside the initalisation.

Answer (score 1):

useState does not update synchronously. This means that although you setEndTime and then try to read it, the chances are it has not been updated yet.

Also, setting state causes a re-render. This is unnessasary when measuring performance. You can instead use `useRef` to hold the timing value in a reference variable.

```
export default function App() {
  const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false);
  const timer = React.useRef(null)

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Pressable
        onPress={() => {
          timer.current = new Date().getTime()
          setVisible(true);
        }}>
        <Text>Show modal</Text>
      </Pressable>
      <Pressable
        onPress={() => {
          setVisible(false);
          alert(new Date().getTime() - timer.current)
        }}>
        <Text>Hide modal</Text>
      </Pressable>

      {visible ? (
        <Card>
          <Text>Modal content</Text>
        </Card>

      ) : null}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Here, we are setting the visible value and storing timestamp on press. And when the user presses hide, we use the stored time to calculate the time elapsed.

Comment: hey, i tried your solution but it gives a type error on line `timer.current` saying `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'null'.

Comment: You seem to be using Typescript, you can fix the issue by setting a union type:  `const timer = React.useRef<null | number>(null)`